# Ruby On Rails Fails on Fresh Ubuntu, Mint, and Fedora Because of Debug inspector failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have tried in the last week with a fresh copy of Linux mint 18 Ubuntu 16.04 and fedora 24?(the latest one).  All 3 give me the error with debug inspector.

xjackparsons93@93 ~/ty $ bundle install

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1xcia5udebug_inspector-0.0.2/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160808-7120-px14tj.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1xcia5udebug_inspector-0.0.2/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1xcia5udebug_inspector-0.0.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1wwehr9byebug-9.0.5/gems/byebug-9.0.5/ext/byebug
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160808-7120-1p1pe88.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1wwehr9byebug-9.0.5/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1wwehr9byebug-9.0.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-705k68sqlite3-1.3.11/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160808-7120-1mdxtv9.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-705k68sqlite3-1.3.11/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-705k68sqlite3-1.3.11/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1p1mgmsnokogiri-1.6.8/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160808-7120-f0fc55.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1p1mgmsnokogiri-1.6.8/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20160808-7120-1p1mgmsnokogiri-1.6.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.





I tried sudo gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2' , and the results were 
xjackparsons93@93 ~/ty $ sudo gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'
[sudo] password for xjackparsons93: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debug_inspector:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160808-8013-10my2bw.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
```

This problem is not affecting my MacBook Pro only linux boxes

Comment: The error message above informs you that you are missing a ruby.h, a ruby header file that usually points out, there is a development package missing. With fedora 24 mentioned above you can use the package manager to search for missing files e.g. `dnf provides */ruby.h` resulting in some `ruby-devel-x.x.x` packages. `dnf install ruby-devel` will solve at least the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This can help you:**

If you have issues, first make sure you have all the tooling necessary to compile C extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
```

It’s possible that you don’t have important development header files installed on your system. (This has never happened to me personally, but I have it on good authority that otherwise good and noble Ruby developers run into this.) Here’s what you should do if you should find yourself in this situation:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Please report it as a bug if this doesn’t work for you (see [Getting Help](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/getting_help.html) for details).